# logical argument in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to take the second element of `table(mtcars$cyl == 6)[2]` which is 7, but rather I would like to use `TRUE` statement without assigning any `columnname`. Many thanks in advance.

```
     table(mtcars$cyl == 6)[FALSE]
named integer(0)

      > table(mtcars$cyl == 6)[[TRUE]]
    [1] 25
    > table(mtcars$cyl == 6)
    
    FALSE  TRUE 
       25     7 
    > table(mtcars$cyl == 6)[TRUE]

FALSE  TRUE 
   25     7
```

Expected answer: 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRUE` should be a character, not a logical.

```
x <- table(mtcars$cyl == 6)
x["TRUE"]

# TRUE 
#    7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sum` here -

```
sum(mtcars$cyl == 6)
#[1] 7
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tabyl`

```
library(janitor)
tabyl(mtcars, cyl) %>% 
    filter(cyl ==6) %>%
    pull(n)
#[1] 7
```